# Spring Roo: how to show html page outside default layout, as a standalone jsp without default layout

Tags: html, css, jsp, spring-roo

For one jsp page I need that page not to be "rendered" using the default layout. So no header, footer, nothing. Only the plain JSP page as it is.

At the moment the page shows correctly, yet inside a frame, with the banner, header and footer of Spring (default.jspx if I'm not wrong)

Answer (score 1):

As eruiz says, just set up Tiles config as needed.

To do that you need to create new custom-layout.jspx file on "webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/". You can copy an existing layout like "default.jspx" and remove header, footer and that elements that you don't want on your view.

When you finish that step, you need to go to your "views.xml" file and modify layout attribute for your view to use the new one.

Now your view has a different layout.

PD: Remember to relaunch your application to view the changes.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just, set up Tiles config as needed.